# OnePlus One randomly soft-reboots after wipe

Tags: reboot, oneplus-one

This didn't use to be a problem until  I wiped my phone and reinstalled 05Q.

Now, approximately every hour or so my 1+1 spontaneously soft-reboots. It's not a hard reboot; my phone is encrypted and it never asks me for the encryption password. It just randomly reboots for no reason, sometimes when I'm using it, sometimes when I'm not.

Sometimes, after doing so, the start of the remaining battery usage information automatically resets to the time of the reboot. Other times, it doesn't reset, and just displays random blank intervals. The reboots are driving me nuts, since they recently made me miss an alarm.

It's not WiFi or Bluetooth or even data (I've tried disabling all of these)... for the life of me I can't figure out what it is. Before the wipe, I also had 05Q, but it had been upgraded from earlier versions. But after wiping I just installed it directly. It's obviously a software issue, since it didn't use to be the case until I wiped and re-imaged it. I thought it might be because I used ART after the reinstall instead of Dalvik, but the problem persisted after I switched back to Dalvik and cleared the cache.

I can't figure out how to diagnose it either; I don't know which log files to look at because it's a soft-reboot and not a hard-reboot.

Any ideas on how I can fix or even diagnose this? It's driving me nuts; I'm missing reminders because of it.oneplus

---

#### Edit:

Here's the data from adb logcat...

```
(...)
[ 07-22 14:15:12.668 15394:17283 D/LBSSystemMonitorService ] handleMessage what - 7
[ 07-22 14:15:12.668 15394:17283 D/Wiper_jni ] Send Passive Location.[ 07-22 14:15:59.998 15394:15589 D/PowerManagerService ] acquireWakeLock: ignoring request from android
[ 07-22 14:16:59.998 15394:15589 D/PowerManagerService ] acquireWakeLock: ignoring request from android
[ 07-22 14:17:56.398 15394:15589 D/PowerManagerService ] acquireWakeLock: ignoring request from android
[ 07-22 14:17:59.998 15394:15589 D/PowerManagerService ] acquireWakeLock: ignoring request from android
[ 07-22 14:18:38.408   213:  213 I/rmt_storage ] rmt_storage_connect_cb: clnt_h=0xf conn_h=0xb88b9fb8
[ 07-22 14:18:38.408   213:  213 I/rmt_storage ] rmt_storage_rw_iovec_cb: /boot/modem_fs1: clnt_h=0x1: req_h=0x17 msg_id=3: R/W request received
[ 07-22 14:18:38.408   213:  213 I/rmt_storage ] wakelock acquired: 1, error no: 42
[ 07-22 14:18:38.408   213:  620 I/rmt_storage ] rmt_storage_client_thread: /boot/modem_fs1: clnt_h=0x1 Unblock worker thread (th_id: -1198791904)
```

Comment: It never happened to me so it's just a guess. Since you're certain that it happens every hour or so, you may do `adb logcat -v long > <FILE> ` before the completion of an hour and let it run until the soft-reboot happens (remember the time when soft-reboot happened). Now open the file and use the time to start searching for anything that resulted in soft-reboot (I guess it should be related to killing of `system_server` or `zygote`).

Comment: @Firelord: thanks, I'll give it a try. It's not certain to be every hour, rather it just happens more often around that time frame. I've seen it go multiple hours without rebooting and I've also seen it reboot much sooner, but overall it's around every hour.

Comment: @Firelord: Actually, it seems like this time it occurred *exactly* at the hour... at least accurate to a minute! I've edited the question to include the log I got; any idea how I should interpret it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. [As described on `/r/oneplus`](https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/2lumv7/first_random_reboot_on_44s_and_maybe_a_solution/clycds2), it seems to have been due to me denying "Keep Awake" permission to Android System to avoid the annoying wakelock bug that drains my battery.

It seems that denying it to Google Play Services should be enough here.